# MongoDB Cluster Shard with no primary and only one secondary active

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-cluster, mongodb-replica

My MongoDB Sharded Cluster has 3 shards with each shard running on 3 replicas. To summarize:

```
Config Server:
  shardcfg1.server.com:27018
  shardcfg2.server.com:27018
  shardcfg3.server.com:27018
Shard1:
  shard11.server.com:27000 (P)
  shard12.server.com:27000 (S)
  shard13.server.com:27000 (S)
Shard2:
  shard21.server.com:27000 (S)
  shard22.server.com:27000 (STARTUP)
  shard23.server.com:27000 (Unhealthy - invalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us)
Shard3:
  shard31.server.com:27000 (S)
  shard32.server.com:27000 (P)
  shard33.server.com:27000 (S)
```

If you see the state above the problem lies in `SHARD2`.

- No Primary in `SHARD2`
- How did the replica set config marked `shard23.server.com` as not a member

The secondary `shard21.server.com` can be used to get the dump so potentially there is no data loss. However, I have no clue whatsoever about how do I stabilize the cluster again?

How would I remove the `SHARD2` completely from the cluster? Or How should I reinitialize the shard with the same servers again?

Comment: Each shard is a replica set.  Do not attempt to remove the shard from the cluster unless you confirm the chunks have migrated to another shard.  Assuming you have valid backups you can attempt to get the shard2 replica set up and running without restore from backup.  Log files should reveal why shard22.server.com is STARTUP and not promoting a leader election.  2 of 3 servers is a majority and leader election is expected.  shard23 will likely need to be removed from the shard2 replica set and re-added causing an initial sync thus restoring back to a PSS model.

Comment: Replica set initialization problems can occur if inconsistent configuration changes are applied across the replica set.  For example, if the replica set was created with no internal auth, then one member has keyfile auth applied it will have problems.  Verify configuration consistency across the replica set.  Try to connect individually to each member to verify connectivity is possible.

Comment: @barrypicker I guess If we remove the shard the draining process is all about migrating chunks in the rearranged ranges. Please correct me if I am wrong because if I am wrong what I have been doing at my cluster is horrific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small detail that I missed which in turn came out to be the key for the solution: The cluster was managed by Mongo-MMS!

**Solution:**

So I had one secondary, another server in STARTUP mode and the third one that ridiculously declared itself as not part of the replica set! The entire cluster is managed by MMS. I did shut down all three of the servers. Now I just simply started the secondary available in standalone mode to get the backup of the entire database.

During this period I removed this shard from my cluster, the draining stuck because there was no primary in the shard. However, one odd thing happened and the automation agent on these servers was removed. Once the backup was complete, I started back the `mongod` of the server which was secondary and had data on it. 
The terminal sadly did show SECONDARY, however when I checked rs.status() it showed three servers, I did remember splicing off one of the rogue servers. That's when it struck me the MMS was managing the config of these replica set.

I quickly reconfigured with force flag as true after removing the rogue server. So now I have two servers, one in secondary and the other in startup mode. A few seconds after reconfiguration! Voila! The secondary promoted itself to the primary.

A long fight but glad to say never needed to restore the backup or rework the entire shard!